# Do you use the inner or outer degrees of a right-angled triangle when calculating the vertical component of a vector

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm given the assignment of finding the vertical component of vector a - b. Below is an image of vector A. ||A|| = 6. I need to calculate side y.

I was following the assignment and tried solving y by doing; y = 6sin(50) since 360-310=50. When I checked the results it turned out I was wrong because according to khanacademy you must calculate y by 6sin(310).

So my question: Why must you use the 310 degrees rather than 50 degrees? I thought you always needed to use the amount of degrees of the inside of a right-angled triangle...

[image: https://ka-perseus-graphie.s3.amazonaws.com/d9656c21f22dd9ba5c46bf122668f720a65b3c80.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors have direction and magnitude, but they don't have a fixed "initial point". All vectors pointing in the same direction and of the same length are equivalent.

So, translate the vector so that its base point is the origin. It will then be pointing in the same direction as it is now--sort of southeast-ish. Now measure the angle that this vector has with the positive $x$-axis (**always measuring counterclockwise!!!**). It is $310^\circ$, or $-50^\circ$.

The fact that this translated vector points from the origin into the 4th quadrant should tell you that its horizontal component ($x$-coordinate of the terminal end) is positive and that its vertical component ($y$-coordinate of the terminal end) is negative.

Comment: I feel like I understand your answer, but I don't understand why the direction matters. What if we were to flip/mirror the triangle vertically? None of the sides will become shorter, they are still the same size, but following your "algorithm" (I'm refering to this part: Now measure the angle that this vector has with the positive x-axis (always measuring counterclockwise!!!)) I would have to use 50 degrees instead and the sign would be different.

Comment: That's exactly right--the component(s) will change precisely because the arrow is now pointing in a different direction. You must bear in mind that a vector isn't just a distance, it is a *directed* distance. Do you understand what I mean by that?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't stress this--the components are measured with respect to a fixed pair of axes (positive $x$- and $y$-axes). So "right" is a positive horizontal component, while "left" is a negative horizontal component, just as "up" and "down" are positive and negative vertical components. See?

Comment: I think I'm just going to accept the fact that I should always measure counterclockwise from the x plane rather than think about it. I do understand that vectors have a direction and that the sign changes depending on the direction. One question, though: Does direction matter because we're dealing with vectors here or should I apply this algorithm on any right-angled triangle? Thanks alot for your time and effort by the way.

Comment: It's strictly about vectors. Distances in geometric figures are typically always positive, perhaps with qualifying words such as "above" or "below" if needed. Think: "geometry=distance", "vectors=directed distance" (yes, I know this is vague but it's something to hang your hat on). I recommend imagining a set of "floating $x$- and $y$-axes" that you can slide around and pin the origin at the base point of the vector for the sake of measuring components. That's really what's going on. I hope that helps--keep with it!

Answer (score 1):

Because $\sin(50\,^{\circ})$ is positive, which is incorrect for your negative $y$-value. Using 310 will give you the correct sign for $y$.

Comment: How can y be negative? It's just the length of that side, right? I still don't understand it.

Comment: In general, the negative sign is important (to signify direction). y points downwards, hence it is negative. If you're just concerned with the value then I guess it does not matter, but you should always use the correct angle and THEN decide if the sign is important/what it means.

Comment: The components are **oriented**, meaning that direction is important. Taking five steps northeast is not the same as taking five steps southwest, is it? The positive $x$- and $y$-axes point in the direction of positive orientation. Lengths measured in the opposite direction(s) have a "$-$" sign attached.